# ReflectionException Error during Upgrade to Magento 2.2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.3

Am getting this Error while Compiling during upgrade from **2.1.10 to 2.2.3.**

> ```
> [ReflectionException]
>   Class \Magestore\GiftVoucher\Api\GiftVoucherProduct\GiftvoucherProductRepos
>   itoryInterface does not exist
> ```

I checked, Every folder is there **i.e. Magestore, GiftVoucher, Api, GiftVoucherProduct** is there. Inside **'GiftVoucherProduct'** there is a file named `'GiftvoucherProductRepositoryInterface.php'`

Please anyone resolve this error.

I have done few fixes which are mentioned on net, but nothing worked out.

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

**ReflectionException is occured when some class or some interface is not found.**

**it is generally coming from generated directory.**

Below is the way to resolved the error

**Run below commands in sequence from your terminal :**

- rm -rf generated
- rm -rf var/cache , rm -rf var/page_cache , rm -rf var/view_processed
- php bin/magento setup:upgrade
- php bin/magento setup:di:compile
- php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
- php bin/magento cache:clean
- php bin/magento cache:flush